# Where does SafariOnline store downloaded books?

Tags: ebook-reader

I used the [Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/) "[Safari to Go](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/apps)" app to download a book to its "Offline Bookbag". In what format is the book stored? I ask because I'm hoping to use a reader other than Safari's own app to read the downloaded book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Nexus 7, my downloaded books go in `/Android/data/com.safaribooksonline/files/zips`. They are stored in `xhtml` directories which includes various metadata, images and the chapters themselves as xhtml documents.

While these look vaguely HTML like, they certainly can't be rendered in Chrome or other web browsers directly, you just end up seeing all of the mark-up as text.

I don't know how standard the xhtml format is for e-books, or whether other readers could understand the format Safari uses, but hopefully this helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Plain html, concatenate them, include the css and images and add html extension or  so the browser knows what to do

Comment: As a developer, I more-or-less get the idea of this answer. But most of visitors here are probably not a developer and might get lost. It'd be better if you could explain the steps in more detail (e.g. linking some steps to SO, or blog that already explain this is still acceptable)